# Get url src of current Iframe from javascript inside the iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, url-parameters

I have javascript inside an iframe but need to get the src - because it has a dynamic url param

```
<iframe src="https://my-site.com/quizzes/inv/resulttest?ver=38.13945791293562&user_id=6" class="frame" id="myId" width="100%" height="450px" style="position: relative; display: initial;"></iframe>
```

How do I get the src of this? I tried document.getElementById('myId') but it is saying null.

Comment: What do you mean by `javascript inside an iframe but need to get the src`?

Comment: @AndrewL64 the javascript is in the file with the iframe src not on the site that is showing the iframe

Comment: Ok, so the webpage inside the iframe has some JavaScript. And you want the src. Q1. What is the JavaScript for? Q2. You want to retrieve the src of what element from the webpage inside the iframe?

Comment: @AndrewL64 the src of the iframe. I need the user_id

Comment: If you just want the `6` from the iframe src, why would you need access to JavaScript inside the iframe webpage when you can retrieve the `6` out of the iframe src from the site showing the iframe too?

Comment: Becuase the javascript is called on test completion from a 3rd party source in which I send an xmlhttprequest from the javascript back to the site that I am showing the iframe from to save the test results @AndrewL64

Comment: Can you just access `window.location.href` inside of the iframe? Content rendered inside of an iframe has no idea that it's inside of an iframe. `src` is just the URL of the page to load - the page inside the iframe behaves more or less like any other webpage. The page inside of an iframe cannot access the `<iframe>` element itself.